# remote view android similar to vnc

Tags: android, tcp, client, viewer

I know this will seem odd. I am wondering is there a way I can stream my android homescreen TO my desktop, Sure I can download vnc, and do that. But I want to make my own and learn how to do it. I did remote viewer in C#, and in C# I used bitmap. Now, would I need to use bitmap in java/android to remote view my phones homescreen or is there more efficient way to do that?